# Does postgres check the number of avilable threads while processing queries?

Tags: postgresql

I'm wondering if Postgres manage it's workers when running queries:

Suppose I'm, running  a heavy query which run parallel (with multiple workers to complete the query faster). while Postgres start running the query there are just 4 free workers.
After some minutes, other queries finished and more workers are available.

Does Postgres increase the number of workers of current working query to complete it faster?
(i.e start running the query with X workers, and complete it with X+Y workers)

I'm wondering if it will good to split this query:

```
select person_tbl.tdm, sum((st_distance (person_tbl.geo, location_tbl.geo) < 1000)::INT),
```

sum((st_distance (person_tbl.geo, location_tbl.geo) < 1500)::INT)
from persons as person_tbl, locations as location_tbl
where person_tbl.geo is not null
group by person_tbl.tdm

into 2 queries (which execute from 2 application threads in parallel:

```
select person_tbl.tdm, sum((st_distance (person_tbl.geo, location_tbl.geo) < 1000)::INT)
from persons as person_tbl, locations as location_tbl
where person_tbl.geo is not null
group by person_tbl.tdm
```

and:

```
select person_tbl.tdm, sum((st_distance (person_tbl.geo, location_tbl.geo) < 1500)::INT)
from persons as person_tbl, locations as location_tbl
where person_tbl.geo is not null
group by person_tbl.tdm
```

(**while there are more queries which run on the server**)

If Postgres set a fix number of workers per query depends on the available workers at start query execution, than split the query above into 2 queries will be better, otherwise I can leave it with one query instead of 2.

Comment: "*start running the query with X workers, and complete it with X+Y workers*" - to my knowledge this will not happen. The number of workers planned at the beginning will be the number used throughout the entire runtime of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of parallel workers is determined at two points in time:

- during query planning, the optimizer determines how many workers it would like to have
- at the start of query execution, it is determined how many of the `max_parallel_workers` are already in use, and the number of workers is fixed

The number of workers won't change during query execution.